vimdiff using scp between different accounts
When I want to do vimdiff between a local file and a remote file on a different machine, I do it like this :
$vimdiff file1.tcl scp://129.254.32.30//home/ckim/file2.tcl

But my current local account is is not ckim. In this case the remote machine expects me to enter a password for my local account which doesn't exist in the remote machine. How can I do this?  I tried (when my local ID is etri)
$vimdiff file1.tcl scp:ckim@//129.254.32.30//home/ckim/file2.tcl

but didn't work.

The URI form should be scp://ckim@129.254.32.30//home/ckim/file2.tcl I think - see for example man scp
